# Red "STAGING" text when casting using chromecast

Tags: google-chrome, chromecast

I am currently using google chromecast to stream videos to my TV from my local server. I get a red colored "staging" text at the top of the media player.Why do we get that and how to remove it ?

Comment: What App ID are you using? What sample are you trying?

Comment: I am trying to run the sample available in this path -https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloVideo-chrome.I havent registered the app yet.

Comment: There was an older app id in that code which I have removed. Sync with the latest version of the sample app code and make sure the only app id is on line 74: chrome.cast.media.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APP_ID